# Adding multiple views to view controller inside a tab controller using swift

Tags: swift, interface-builder, ios8

I have a tabbedviewcontroller with different viewcontrollers connected but for each view controller I'm trying to have multiple views inside them. How can I add these views? Programmatically using swift or is there a way to do it in interface builder xcode 6?

Comment: You can multiple UIViews within a view.  Programmatically or by dragging a View from the Object library into the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Search for UIView in the object library and drag a view into your view controller. You can then resize it to your preferences. You will then want to create an outlet for each view in your view controller so that you can interact with them in your code.

[image]

Comment: OHHH okay so each view though I can connect to a separate view controller? How do I resize the viewcontrollers to fit the view?

Comment: Yes. Each view controller can have multiple views. Once you have dragged the view into the view controller just click and drag the corners until the guidelines line up with the edges of the view controller.